# How to update table with Many condition

Tags: sql, database

I need to update multiple columns in a table with multiple condition.

For example, this is my Query

```
update Table1 
set weight= d.weight,
    stateweight=d.stateweight,
    overallweight=d.overallweight 
from
     (select * from table2)d 
      where table1.state=d.state and
          table1.month=d.month and 
          table1.year=d.year
```

If table matches all the three column (State,month,year), it should update only weight column and if it matches(state ,year) it should update only the stateweight column and if it matches(year) it should update only the overallweight column

NOTE: I can't write an update query for each condition separately because its a huge Table  pls help us

Comment: Which dbms? (The query posted isn't ANSI SQL.)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, here's another one, perhaps what you're looking for:

```
update Table1 
set weight = case when table1.state = d.state and
                       table1.month = d.month and 
                       table1.year = d.year
                  then d.weight
                  else weight end,
     stateweight =  case when table1.state = d.state and
                              table1.month <> d.month and 
                              table1.year = d.year
                  then d.stateweight 
                  else stateweight end,
    overallweight = case when table1.state <> d.state and
                              table1.month <> d.month and 
                              table1.year = d.year
                  then d.overallweight 
                  else overallweight end
from
     (select * from table2)d 
      where
          table1.year=d.year
```

Note that columns will be updated to it's own value, i.e. same value but still in transaction.

Case with overallweight may need other conditions, but I'm not sure how you want it.

Old answer:

This may work, depending on the dbms you're using:

```
update Table1 
set (weight,
     stateweight,
     overallweight) = 
     (select * from table2 d 
      where table1.state = d.state and
            table1."month" = d."month" and 
            table1."year" = d."year")
```

Year and month columns are delimited here because that's are reserved words.

*The following feature outside Core SQL-2003 is used:
T641, "Multiple column assignment"*

Comment: hi,tks for replay, the above query which satisfies only one condition what about the other two (if it matches(state ,year) it should update only the stateweight column and if it matches(year) it should update only the overallweight column)

Comment: Sorry, obviously I didn't read carefully enough... Will take another look later.

Answer (score 0):

```
with
cte as  (   select      t1.Year,
                        t1.Month,
                        t1.State,
                        Weight      =   MAX(case
                                                when t1.State = t2.State and t1.Month = t2.Month
                                                then t2.Weight
                                                else t1.Weight
                                            end),
                        StateWeight =   MAX(case
                                            when t1.State = t2.State and t1.Month = t2.Month
                                            then t2.StateWeight
                                            else t1.StateWeight
                                        end),
                        Overweight  =   MAX(t2.Overweight)
            from        Table1  as  t1
            inner join  Table2  as  t2  on  t1.Year = t2.Year
            group by    t1.Year, t1.Month, t1.State)
update      t1
set         Weight  =   tv.Weight,
            StateWeight =   tv.StateWeight,
            Overweight = tv.Overweight
from        Table1  as  t1
inner join  cte     as  tv  on  t1.Year = tv.Year
                            and t1.Month = tv.Month
                            and t1.State = tv.State;
```

it works